# How can I create all has_one relationships automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following models:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_one: :basic_metric
  has_one: :complex_metric
end


class BasicMetric < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end

class ComplexMetric < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Once a `post` is created, both `basic_metric` and `complex_metric` are `nil`:

```
p = Post.first
p.basic_metric # => nil
p.complex_metric # => nil
```

And because of how my app is going to work, the `BasicMetricsController` and `ComplexMetricsController` only have the update method. So I would like to know if there is a way to create them as soon as a `post` is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very common way of accomplishing this is using [ActiveRecord callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)

```rb
class Post
  after_create :create_metrics

  private

  def create_metrics
    # methods created by has_one, suggested in the comments
    create_basic_metric(additional_attrs)
    create_complex_metric(additional_attrs)
  end
end
```

Another option you have is to overwrite the method created by `has_one`, i.e.:

```rb
class Post
  has_one: :basic_metric
  has_one: :complex_metric

  def basic_metric
    super || create_basic_metric(additional_attrs)
  end

  def complex_metric
    super || create_complex_metric(additional_attrs)
  end
end
```

This way they won't be created automatically with any new post, but created on demand when the method is called.

Comment: I would use `create_basic_metric(some_attrs)` instead of `BasicMetric.create(post_id: id, some_attrs)`. That way the new metrics are associated to the post object right away https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-belongs-to

Comment: You are right, @arieljuod! Do you want to make that update?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one,

```
post = Post.first
post.build_basic_metric
post.build_complex_metric
```

This will help you to build/create the has_one association object if record not saved by default use `post.save` at the end.

If you need this in modal you can use like this,

```
class Post
  after_create :build_association_object

  private

  def create_metrics
    self.build_basic_metric 
    self.build_complex_metric
    # save # (optional)
  end
end
```